# localization: fetching translation words via Ext.Ajax.request in Extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

In my Extjs application, I need to fetch an array of translated words which I'm doing with the help of AJAX request.

Since AJAX runs in the background why does it not populate the text as the labels of the components in the real time.

Is there any way to make AJAX populate in real time?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With out looking at your code I can only be general.

Most Ajax calls are make with helper function that wait for `"200"` (completed) response from the server and after that dose what ever with the response.

It waits for the `"200"` response so it dose not try to work with a half finished response, and make errors.

You can brake the Ajax calls in to smaller segments (one call from one box, and so on)

But there is not a good way to work with Ajax responses before you are sure you have all the file/text that is in the Ajax response.

Hope that this helps clear it up a bit.

Comment: That all depends on your code, but in general you would just set a variable to `false` when you start the ajax call and back to `true` when it finished, and check to see if the variable is `true` or `false` before you allowed user input. It would also be good to let the user know that its waiting on something so they don't think it locked up on them.